# Preview or debug (dry-run or trace) systemctl actions (start, stop, restart, etc.)

Tags: systemd, debugging, systemctl

Without having to manually trace dependencies, e.g. with `systemctl show` or `systemctl cat`, and manually inspect the state of the system with `systemctl status` and `systemctl list-units`, is there a way to preview what a `systemctl stop|start|restart` would do?

Failing that, after the fact, is there a way to show a trace of which jobs were queued and why?

The kind of trace I would like to see in either case is something like:

```
starting X due to user request
adding Y to the transaction because it is required by X
adding Z1, Z2, Z3 because they are wanted by Y
…
```

PS: The `--dry-run` option is only available on later versions of systemd than the one I have, and [is documented](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--dry-run) to only be supported on certain operations that are **not relevant for my use case**.

Comment: PPS: I tried a `systemctl poweroff --dry-run` on my workstation (systemd version 237) as a normal non-root user, and it simply ignored the `--dry-run` option and shut my computer down. A bug in systemd, or a lack of understanding of the documentation on my part?

Comment: Have you looked at `systemctl list-dependencies <unit>`?

Comment: Yes, `list-dependencies` is in the same category as `show`, `cat` etc., i.e. requires manual work to interpret for my use case. For one thing, it does not seem to follow the symlinks for `WantedBy=`, so some units are obviously missing from the list.

Answer (score 0):

It depends:
If other units do not rely on your unit, you could replace the actual commands you unit executes with a dummy command that just prints or logs its parameters.
However for daemon-like processes it would be a bit tricky as they should not terminate.

As some units can only work when other units were started actually, simulation is always limited.